# Helicon ISAPI_REWRITE for masking folder

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, isapi, isapi-rewrite

I would like to use the Helicon ISAPI_REWRITE module to rewrite a url:

123.45.67.89/folder

to

www.site.com

I need to mask the IP/folder due to an IIS structure change.  The reason why I don't want to get into, but it's valid based on the setup.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this more like a ServerFault question ? If I understand correctly, you are asking how you should configure the ISAPI_REWRITE product from Helicon Tech.

Comment: Yes, I saw another ISAPI_REWRITE question answered on this forum, I'll add there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is to go to the ICONIC isapi rewrite utility, which is free, and implement a rewrite rule like: http://iirf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=209315